# how to bind an entire frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I will be using bind to start and stop by pressing a specific key, a stopwatch within frame class. I have tested it without a class and with a simplier interface, and it worked; hence the implementation which I have done to put the code inside the class is not right. Appreciate it if you could help me with this.

```
      
class StartOne(tk.Frame):



    def __init__(self, parent, controller, bg="green"):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        def button_timerstart(self,event=None):
            if running==False:
                start_timer()


        def button_timerstop(self,event=None):
            if running==True:
                stop_timer()


        self.bind("<Return>",button_timerstart )
        self.bind("<space>",button_timerstop)
```

Start a stopwatch by pressing return button, and stop it by pressing the spacebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your root widget has maintains keyboard focus.  You can either switch the bind calls to your root window, or you can manually assign keyboard focus to your frame.

Here is an example of the later:

```
class StartOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, bg="green"):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.bind("<Return>", self.button_timerstart )
        self.bind("<space>", self.button_timerstop)
        self.running = False
        self.focus_set()


    def button_timerstart(self,event=None):
        if self.running==False:
            start_timer()


    def button_timerstop(self,event=None):
        if self.running==True:
            stop_timer()
```

Comment: I have tried it and it works. Thank you so much! I was really struggling with this

Comment: Sure thing.  Please mark the answer as correct if you don't have any further questions @888888